# Why is UI not updating sometimes using recyclerview and data binding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I'm creating a to-do app using MVVM with Room, LiveData, a RecyclerView with ListAdapter and data binding. When I check off an item, it jumps to the bottom of the list (sorted by incomplete, then complete). I'm also using a different layout for completed items where the text becomes italic and grayed out. Usually when I check a box, it jumps down and turns gray/italic, but sometimes it stays black. How can I track down this issue, or could it be a problem with the data binding library?

```
// ToDoItemAdapter.kt

const val ITEM_UNCHECKED = 0
const val ITEM_CHECKED = 1

class ToDoItemAdapter(private val onCheckboxClick: (ToDoItem) -> Unit, private val onCardClick: (ToDoItem) -> Unit): ListAdapter<ToDoItem, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(ToDoItemDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            ITEM_CHECKED -> ViewHolderChecked.from(parent)
            else -> ViewHolderUnchecked.from(parent)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is ViewHolderChecked -> {
                val toDoItem = getItem(position)
                holder.bind(toDoItem, onCheckboxClick, onCardClick)
            }
            is ViewHolderUnchecked -> {
                val toDoItem = getItem(position)
                holder.bind(toDoItem, onCheckboxClick, onCardClick)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val toDoItem = getItem(position)
        return when (toDoItem.completed) {
            true -> ITEM_CHECKED
            false -> ITEM_UNCHECKED
        }
    }

    class ViewHolderChecked private constructor(private val binding: ChecklistItemCheckedBinding)
        : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(toDoItem: ToDoItem, onCheckboxClick: (ToDoItem) -> Unit, onCardClick: (ToDoItem) -> Unit) {
            binding.todoItem = toDoItem
            binding.checkboxCompleted.setOnClickListener {
                onCheckboxClick(toDoItem)
            }
            binding.cardTodo.setOnClickListener {
                onCardClick(toDoItem)
            }
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolderChecked {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                return ViewHolderChecked(ChecklistItemCheckedBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false))
            }
        }
    }
```

In the adapter, when the checkbox is clicked it winds up running a function in the viewmodel:

```
fun toggleCheckbox(toDoItem: ToDoItem) {
    toDoItem.completed = !toDoItem.completed
    update(toDoItem)
}
```

update(toDoItem) calls a suspend function and basically updates the data in the Room database through a repository on a background thread.

In the fragment, I'm setting the binding equal to the viewmodel, setting the lifecycle owner, setting the adapter, and then setting an observer on the allToDoItems list:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding.checklistViewModel = checklistViewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    val adapter = ToDoItemAdapter(onCheckboxClickHandler, onCardClickHandler)
    binding.itemsList.adapter = adapter
    checklistViewModel.allToDoItems.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { allItems ->
        allItems?.let {
            adapter.submitList(allItems.sortedWith(compareBy(
                {it.completed},
                {it.description}))
            )
        }
    })
    return binding.root
}
```